# Add JSDoc @deprecated to mapped type

Tags: typescript, types, jsdoc

I have a function that returns an object with variable key names:

```
return {[something]: 'test'} as {[K in Something]: string}
```

Is there a way I can add the @deprecated flag through JSDoc in that key? I have tried adding it right above the `[K in Something]` but it doesn't work.